# Viewing image stored in database using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to view an image that was stored in my database and the what the database stores is the filename of the image

This is the code where it fetches the data

```
function fetch_data()  
 {  
      ob_start();
      $output = '';  
      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "it180p");  
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM incidentreport ORDER BY reportId ASC";  
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {       
      $output .= '<tr>  
                          <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["school"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["gradeLvl"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["section"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["dateTime"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["incidentType"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["incidentDesc"].'</td>  
                            <td>'.$row["sender"].'</td> 
                          <td>'.$row["invPeople"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["studStatYes"].'</td> 
                            <td>'.$row["studStatNo"].'</td> 
                              <td>'.$row["numInvPeople"].'</td> 
                              <td>'.$row["attachment"].'</td> 
                     </tr>  
                          ';  
      }  
      return $output;  
 }
```

And this is the code where it views the fetched data

```
<?php foreach($incidentreports as $report) { ?>
                    <tr>                    
                      <td><?php echo $report["school"]; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $report["gradeLvl"]; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $report["section"]; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $report["dateTime"]; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $report["reportDate"]; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $report["incidentType"]; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $report["incidentDesc"]; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $report["invPeople"]; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $report["sender"]; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $report["studStatYes"]; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $report["studStatNo"]; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $report["maleCount"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $report["femaleCount"]; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $report["numInvPeople"]; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo '<img src="uploads/png;base64,'. ( $report["attachment"] ).'"/>'; ?></td>


                    </tr>
```

When i only put "attachment" it only displays the filename so i tried to use the code above. There wasn't any error but the image does not load, it only shows like a broken img icon. I've tried other ways but I'm currently stuck in here and don't know what to do. Would really appreciate it if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,
`/png;base64` this not understood so removed

```
<td><img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$report["attachment"]); ?>"></td>
```

Dont forget to add extension if you didn't saved in db

Comment: Appreciate the help, sir. I tried it and peeked at the source code and it seems to be showing the correct path to the folder and image file though it still shows the broken img icon

Comment: The path location is "http://localhost:80/it180/uploads/3" and the "3" is the image file. I think that it needs to show the file extension (.png) to load the image right?

Comment: I assume you saved file name with its extension

Comment: yeah after thinking about it, i forgot to include the extension, it's my bad

Comment: anyways, you really helped me there. Thanks alot!

Comment: Your always Welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><img src="<?php echo 'your_image_path/'.$report['attachment']); ?>"></td>
```

Try the above code. And "your_image_path" is the image path. example: https://localhost/your_project/uploads/
If you are using codeigniter framework then follow the answer of M.Hemant. That will solve your problem.